# C# Regular Expression to match pattern 'n/n/n' where n are just numbers

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am looking for the regular expression to see if a string matches the format

```
[int]/[int]/[int]
```

e.g.

```
'98/4/76542' or '98/04/76542'
```

PS : I do NOT want to check a date is valid but only that the format matches the 'n/n/n' where n is a number.

Edit : Removed the incoorect and misleading 'nn/nn/nnnn', just n\n\n should be sufficient, apologies.

Comment: Need to know: Do you really want backslashes?  Also when you say `nn` do you mean exactly two ns?  Because your example has the single digit 4.  And you have five digits in the third group.  Is there any significance to your n's?

Comment: @Mark Byers: And what about that 98? He actually does not want to check for valid dates, but still the example doesn't match the pattern presented so which is it?

Comment: @Mark : Yes! That is exactly why I used that example, it is not meant to be converted to DateTime yet, just checking the formats, leaving the validity of values open for next level.

Comment: @Mark : that is a good question. I was happy with four but even that is no longer up to me at this stage, just verifying the formats before even attempting to change the Calendar Culture to verify the date.

Comment: @Mark : More complete yes, complicated no! I am breaking up my validation process to stages, delegating the validity of the actual date to the next stage.

Comment: @Ray : woops , no That was meant to be '\' slash, I just realised it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
^\d+/\d+/\d+$
```

Comment: The string `98\4\76542` would not match that format. You have to allow more digits in the last component.

Comment: @Kirill : I changed the question, apologies for ambiguity.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want this:

```
"^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+$"
```

Note that the regular expression `[0-9]` requires that the digit be one of the following characters: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9. It *excludes* foreign characters that are regarded as digits, such as the Arabic-Indic numeral `٨`. If you want to allow foreign characters that are considered decimal digits, then use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. Here's a [demonstration](http://ideone.com/IUcXE) of the difference.

```
                        1/22/333    ٨/٢/٠
^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+$  True        False
^\d+/\d+/\d+$           True        True
```

Comment: So to match the exact request of the PO *("nn\nn\nnnn")*, it'll be `@"^[0-9]{2}\\[0-9]{2}\\[0-9]{4}$"`

Comment: @Mark : I changed the question, apologies for ambiguity.

Comment: @Arjang: After your edit, the solution should be `@"^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+$"`

Answer (score 2):

This pattern will match digits separated by slashes:

```
^\d+/\d+/\d+$
```

The `+` operator makes sure that there is at least one digit in each component, but there is no upper limit, so for exaple `1/2/33333333333333333333333333333333333333333` is a valid string, but the third component can't be parsed into a 32 bit integer.

You can specify the number of digits so that they fall in a reasonable range, for example:

```
^\d{1,10}/\d{1,10}/\d{1,10}$
```

The backslash is the escape character in a regular string, so that would be written `"^\\d{1,10}/\\d{1,10}/\\d{1,10}$"`, but you can also use a @ delimited string and write it as `@"^\d{1,10}/\d{1,10}/\d{1,10}$"`.

#### Edit:

For a date you might want to be more specific about the number of digits, for example:

```
^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$
```

Comment: I changed the question, apologies for ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to get the extra "can this be a valid date check", you may use `DateTime validInputDate = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, @"dd\MM\yyyy");`. This will throw if the input string is not a valid date matching the format string given.

(Even you stated yuo don't need it, some other searchers may be happy to find this answer here.)

Comment: I would need that at a later stage, I am separating the Format validity and Value validity into separate stages.